# How to display all treeview selections in a messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I`ve been working on a CRM Tool Project in Tkinter now, and I have a function that removes many rows at the same time.
My problem is that before the program deletes the selected rows, I want to display them in a askyesno messagebox. I´ve tried the code below, but in only displays the first row.

```
for item in edit_database_tree.selection():
    item_text = edit_database_tree.item(item, 'values')


response = messagebox.askyesno("Confirmação", f"De certeza que quer remover\n\n{item_text}\n\n da base de dados?")
```

I have tried a for loop for 'item_text', but it only displays one value at a time!

Comment: Combine all of the values in a single `str`ing `item_text`.

Comment: It only shows the first value, just like I did

Comment: Right now you keep replacing the value of `item_text` in the for loop. Instead, you want to combine all of the values. For more info, look at some basic tutorials about `for` loops and examples of how to use them

Answer (score 0):

Since you just overwrite `item_text` in each iteration, so `item_text` will contain only the last item of the for loop.

You need to join *values* in each iteration to a single string instead:

```py
item_text = "\n".join(",".join(edit_database_tree.item(item, "values")) for item in edit_database_tree.selection())
response = messagebox.askyesno("Confirmação", f"De certeza que quer remover\n\n{item_text}\n\n da base de dados?")
```